# Python- help('modules') unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, pyside

I've been playing with QT and python using PySide. I've just done one of the basic [tutorials](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySideTutorials_Clickable_button) . I've closed down python and restarted another session and now whenever I try to list the modules using `help('modules')` the button tutorial runs. If I close the window python crashes. The top of the error message is

```
Process:         Python [2005]
Path:            /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      org.python.python
Version:         2.7.3 (2.7.3)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [1967]

Date/Time:       2013-01-09 12:38:53.307 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          486115 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           12
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  23989 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   7
Anonymous UUID:                      93C97407-5F4D-4A25-83BC-C0116B028ECE

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:    '-[QNSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x116b2fe00'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

My most recent action was to install 'PIP' and download some packages. Does anyone know what is causing this or how to resolve it?

**Edit 1**

I noticed that changing directory meant that the PySide tutorial would not run. It now prints out the available modules as before but it also loads a TK window from any directory.

Comment: Could be a `sitecustomize.py` somewhere which redefines builtin `help` function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed PyOpenGL just before I begun having this issue. Having uninstalled it the issue has also disappeared