# Python crashes when used in combination with Qt

Tags: python, macos, qt, opengl, macports

I followed [this basic tutorial](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html) to let Python open a window designed in Qt Designer. However, the code does not yield the expected result and crashes with

```
-[QNSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

The full error looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/NfGHhYvX).
Googling the error I found that it is [a bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spyderlib/ZaLlVlRWT7M/qKf3Y4cxfr0J) in certain Python related packages like Spyder and [py27-opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14241425/1256347), however `port installed | grep py` shows I don't have [any of those packages](http://pastebin.com/W5wv59ns) (I don't see any mention of spyder or opengl at least).
When I type `python` in Terminal it shows the following version:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54)
```

This seems to be the latest version as running `port upgrade outdated` doesn't install a new version.
What can be the cause of this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Could those packages have been installed with something other than MacPorts?

Comment: Where/how would I check that? When I type `locate spyder` or `locate py-opengl` I do stumble on some references, but these are in the `/opt/local/var/macports/sources` folder which only contains a `Port` file and some `.diff` files. No binaries there.